# lookback/shift in pandas dataframes calling functions

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

If I have the following dataframe:

```
  date       A     B    M     S
 20150101    8     7    7.5   0
 20150101    10    9    9.5   -1
 20150102    9     8    8.5   1
 20150103    11    11   11    0
 20150104    11    10   10.5  0
 20150105    12    10   11    -1
 ...
```

If I want to create another column 'cost' by the following rules:

1. if S < 0,  cost = (M-B).shift(1)*S
2. if S > 0,  cost = (M-A).shift(1)*S
3. if S == 0, cost=0

currently, I am using the following function:

```
def cost(df):
if df[3]<0:
    return np.roll((df[2]-df[1]),1)*df[3]
elif df[3]>0:
    return np.roll((df[2]-df[0]),1)*df[3]
else:
    return 0
df['cost']=df.apply(cost,axis=0)
```

Is there any other way to do it? can I somehow use pandas shift function in user defined functions? thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's generally expensive to do it this way, as you're losing the vector speed advantage when you `apply` a user defined function. Instead, how about using [the numpy version of the ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column):

```
import numpy as np

np.where(df[3] < 0,
    np.roll((df[2]-df[1]),1),
    np.where(df[3] > 0,
        np.roll((df[2]-df[0]),1)*df[3] 
        0))
```

(of course assign it to `df['cost']`).

Comment: Thank you so much, the method is very enlightening to me.

Comment: Thanks, however see unutbu's answer below, which is better.

Answer (score 5):

[`np.where(condition, A, B)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy.where) is the NumPy *elementwise* equivalent of

```
A if condition else B
```

[`np.select(conditions, choices)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) is a generalization of `np.where` which is useful when there are more than two choices.

So, like Ami Tavory's answer except using `np.select`, you could use

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table('data', sep='\s+')
conditions = [S < 0, S > 0]
M, A, B, S = [df[col] for col in 'MABS']
choices = [(M-B).shift(1)*S, (M-A).shift(1)*S]
df['cost'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=0)
```

which yields

```
       date   A   B     M  S  cost
0  20150101   8   7   7.5  0   0.0
1  20150101  10   9   9.5 -1  -0.5
2  20150102   9   8   8.5  1  -0.5
3  20150103  11  11  11.0  0   0.0
4  20150104  11  10  10.5  0   0.0
5  20150105  12  10  11.0 -1  -0.5
```

Comment: Ooh, very nice, I did not know this.